# Service to get/set current entity

Tags: symfony

I have a `Project` entity, which has a controller defining many routes:

`projects/1
projects/1/foo
projects/1/bar`

I need a service to provide the current project. The use case is that I have dependencies in my base twig templates which need to know the current project. i.e. a dropdown project selector that is outside the context of the template the current controller is serving.

I've tried creating a service getting route info with `$container->get('router.request_context');`, however, that only provides a path. I don't want to have to parse the path string if I don't have to.

What is the most proper approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly the solution for your problem is rendering/embedding controller. Of course it's simplest, yet somehow acceptable solution for rendering parts of html with some custom logic apart from current template.

You can read about [rendering/embedding controllers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html#embedding-other-controllers).

Some snippets...

Define `controller:action` (*obviously the logic in my example is pretty straight forward*):

```
/**
 * Generate select input field.
 *
 * @Route("/widget", name="project_widget")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function widgetAction()
{
    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Project');

    // #NOTICE: Wee need master request info, because our widget
    //     is rendered and called as subrequest.
    $masterRequest = $this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest();

    // #NOTICE: You need second parameter as default value in case there is no id in masterRequest route.
    $currentProjectId = $masterRequest->get('id', 0);

    $currentProject = $repo->find($currentProjectId);
    $projects = $repo->findAll();

    return $this->render('project/widget.html.twig', [
        'currentProject' => $currentProject,
        'projects' => $projects,
    ]);
}
```

Then you need to create the template `project/widget.html.twig` for it:

```
<div class="widget_project_selection">
    {% if projects is not empty %}
        <select name="widget_project_selection" id="widget_project_selection">
            <option value="">None</option>
            {% for project in projects %}
                <option value="{{ project.id }}"
                    {# #NOTICE: If this is current project, select it #}
                    {{- currentProject and project.id == currentProject.id
                        ? 'selected="selected"'
                        : '' -}}
                >
                    {{- project.title -}}
                </option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    {% else %}
        <span>{{ 'Sadly, no projects yet :('|trans }}</span>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

and at last (*but not least*) render it somewhere like in `base.html.twig`:

```
{{- render(controller('AppBundle:Project:widget')) -}}
```

I've created for you a [Github repo as reference](https://github.com/broiniac/stackoverflow/tree/master/44372224). It's a small Symfony app with similar setup. You can even run it if you like, don't forget about dependencies and database update thou. Entry point is `/app_dev.php/project/`

Take a look at [widgetAction](https://github.com/broiniac/stackoverflow/blob/master/44372224/src/AppBundle/Controller/ProjectController.php#L18), [widget template](https://github.com/broiniac/stackoverflow/blob/master/44372224/app/Resources/views/project/widget.html.twig) and [example usage](https://github.com/broiniac/stackoverflow/blob/master/44372224/app/Resources/views/base.html.twig#L10) in `base.html.twig`.

**EDIT:** But that's not everything. You said you need a service. If for some reason rendering/embedding controller is not an option for you or you really whant to use a `Service` (as in `Dependency Container`) you can [extend Twig](https://github.com/broiniac/stackoverflow/blob/master/44372224/src/AppBundle/Twig/ProjectExtension.php) and use the [full power of services](https://github.com/broiniac/stackoverflow/blob/master/44372224/src/AppBundle/Service/ProjectService.php).

I've also implemented a Twig Filter as example to show you the real power of Twig Extensions in [here](https://github.com/broiniac/stackoverflow/blob/master/44372224/src/AppBundle/Twig/ProjectExtension.php#L84) and [here (usage in templates)](https://github.com/broiniac/stackoverflow/blob/master/44372224/app/Resources/views/project/widget.html.twig#L4).

Check out [Twig Extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) and [Extending Twig](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/advanced.html#id2) for more info about Twig Extensions.

Also check out `service.yml` for service and extension definitions - if you are not using Symfony3.3+, there will be some additional work to do - [defining service and extension directly](https://github.com/broiniac/stackoverflow/blob/master/44372224/app/config/services.yml#L49).

Comment: `$this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest()` was what I needed to get what I needed in my service, although an embeddable controller is an option I didn't know about. Might be time to refactor. Thanks!

Comment: I'm I helped! I've just updated Github repository with different approach (`TwigExtensions`) and service definition.
I've also extended my answer.

Answer (score -1):

In your controller, you can use type hinting to load the "current" entity via the route.

For example:

```
#myrouter.yml
current_project:
  path: /projects/{project}
```

Separately, your controller...

```
//mycontroller.php
public function myControllerAction(Request $request, Project $project)
{
    //$project is entity (assuming valid) loaded via the route above
    return $this->render('mytemplate.twig', ['project' => $project]);
}
```

Comment: It is unclear how this applies to handling getting the current route in a service so it can be retrieved via twig outside of the template the current controller is rendering. I also do not want to do this in every single controller method.

Comment: I wasn't clear that your intention was to actually leverage a service for this, and assumed you DID want to do this in your Controller, so my mistake. *broiniac* clearly knocked this one out of the park though :)